# Imbalanced classes and statistical power

Tags: unbalanced-classes, statistical-power

When imbalanced classes are an issue, isn't it equivalent to having conditions of low statistical power?  You can have imbalanced sample sizes but with appropriate conditions of effect size, standard deviation, significance level (alpha), the disproportionate sample size isn't a problem a priori.
Am I stating the obvious?

Comment: It is not clear what your question is.

Answer (score 2):

Imbalance doesn't necessarily mean that power is low.

However, power in a comparison with a larger and a smaller group will be largely driven by the size of the smaller group; clearly power could be larger if the same numbers of subjects were allocated more evenly, but if the smaller group is still large enough, power may well be fine either way.

Which is to say, yes, you're correct that if you have the statistical properties you require in terms of power and significance level, you might not be concerned about imbalance.

(Depending on the situation, there can be other concerns with unbalanced classes though; for example see the many posts on imbalance in the response in relation to using logistic regression for classification.)